# IF formulas and conditions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Does anyone know how I can write a formula to make a calculation based on the value of another cell, like

```
IF A1= 1 then C2*D2,  
IF A1= 2 then C2*D3,  
IF A1= 3 then C2*D4,  
... and so on for 40 plus conditions?
```

I think google sheets will only let me have three arguments

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use the [IFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145?hl=en-GB) function

```
=IFS(A2=1, B2*C2, A2=2, B2*C3, A2=3, B2*C4, A2=4, B2*C5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If your data is representative, you can use

```
=C2*index(D2:D,A1)
```

or

```
=C2*indirect("D"&A1+1)
```

to get the nth value in column D where the value of n is stored in A1.